# Android Google API with pictures

Tags: android, google-places-api

Am trying to create an android applictaion which locates points of intrest around the user and displays it. So far i have sucessfully incoporated googleplace api with the help of ravi #androidhive but am still lost as to how to pull pictures from google places as well. furthermore, i am confused as to if a wikitravel api exist and if so where do i get it and how to i get it. Finally if its impossible to get resources from wiki travel api and unable to pull pictures from google places what other resource can i pull from and how do i integrate with my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** The Places API now supports the return of one place photo if available for a [Place Search request](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) and up to ten place photos for a [Place Details request](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details).

If a photos array is returned with your request, you can pass the `photo_reference` from a contained photo object to a [Place Photo request](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos) with the `maxheight` and/or `maxwidth`, `sensor` and `key` parameters:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRvAAAAwMpdHeWlXl-lH0vp7lez4znKPIWSWvgvZFISdKx45AwJVP1Qp37YOrH7sqHMJ8C-vBDC546decipPHchJhHZL94RcTUfPa1jWzo-rSHaTlbNtjh-N68RkcToUCuY9v2HNpo5mziqkir37WU8FJEqVBIQ4k938TI3e7bf8xq-uwDZcxoUbO_ZJzPxremiQurAYzCTwRhE_V0&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

Please see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos) for more details.